# subset a data frame for the minimum value of a column across 20 replicates and 2 treatments

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 4 columns (julian date, treatment, cell, flowers).  There are 20 replicated cells receiving 2 treatments.  I would like to subset the minimum julian date that corresponds to the maximum number of flowers recorded for each cell within each treatment.

example df:

```
Julian date  treatment  cell  flowers
256           1         1      2
261           1         1      3
267           1         1      3 
256           1         2      3
261           1         2      8
267           1         2      6
256           2         1      2
261           2         1      4
267           2         1      6
256           2         2      5
261           2         2      9
267           2         2      9
```

subset would return:

```
Julian date  treatment  cell  flowers
261            1         1     3
261            1         2     8
267            2         1     6
261            2         2     9
```

I am able to almost achieve this subset by first splitting the data frame up by treatment and then using ddply to subset for maximum flower number by cell replicate:

```
ddply(df,'cell', subset, flowers==max(flowers))
```

Then I merge the data frames for each treatment back together. The problem is that I have multiple julian dates with equal flower numbers.  From here I can't figure out how to subset this data frame for minimum julian date by cell and treatment (to eliminate equal maximum flower totals) while also returning the corresponding flower numbers in the final data frame.  Other than manually deleting rows using bracket notation and minus signs.

I am using:

```
aggregate(julian~cell+treatment, data=, min)
```

this works but does not return the flower numbers.

Basically, I'm looking for a nice succinct way to use bracket notation or subset() to return a data frame with the minimum julian dates that correspond to maximum flower numbers for my 20 cells within each treatment that included the flower column. Ideally without taking the roundabout way I have been using.  Hope that makes some sense!  Thanks for any help that anyone can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer `data.table` for these operations, but I'm sure someone has a perfectly good `ddply` solution.

```
> df = data.table(df)
> df[, .SD[which.max(flowers)], by=list(treatment, cell)]
   treatment cell JulianDate flowers
1:         1    1        261       3
2:         1    2        261       8
3:         2    1        267       6
4:         2    2        261       9
```

Also of interest could be the `tapply` or `by` function:

```
tapply(df$flowers, list(df$treatment, df$cell), max)

by(df, list(df$treatment, df$cell), function(x) x[which.max(x$flowers),])
```

Comment: Thanks, definitely what I was looking for!  I'm curious to how this code tells R to pick the lowest julian date when max flower numbers are equal on multiple dates for a given cell and treatment?

Comment: @user3874999 - I think there might be a problem with the code. At the moment `which.max` just picks the first `JulianDate`. I.e., try this code after first running `df <- df[c(1,3,2,4:12),]` - it falls over and picks the wrong one.

Comment: Maybe something like this instead: `df[, list(flowers=max(flowers),Julian=min(Julian[flowers == max(flowers)])) ,by=list(treatment,cell)]`

Comment: Thanks to @thelatemail for the suggestion.  This code seems like it should work, but I am getting unused argument error for `by=list(treatment, cell)`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is df a `data.table` or `data.frame` @user3874999 ?

Comment: I was running @thelatemail suggested code as a `data.frame`.  right, I need to run it as a `data.table`.  that seemed to do the trick.  Thanks, I really appreciate the help.